# Pulling data from a class instance that may not yet exist in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

In my `Data Structures with Java` University Course, we've been tasked with making a simple *Social Network*.

One of the profile methods defined by a given interface is recommend, which is supposed to go into the array of profile objects holding the list of people.
This instance follows, pick one, go into that instance's array follow list and return a profile from there as a suggestion of someone to follow.

I don't really understand anything about how to go about this, because I'm supposed to anticipate an instance of a class which doesn't exist yet.

I don't expect whoever responds to do my homework for me, but any guidance about how to start this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A parameter or variable that has the type of the interface is fine, because the object passed or assigned to it has to implement the interface.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is hard to word and the description is really confusing. When the instance doesn't yet exist, how is it possible to take an instance, pull from it another instance which may not yet exist, and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (very) bare-bones implementation that you can follow as a guide.

Your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List<Profile> profiles;

    // You'll have to figure out how to load these yourself.
    // It sounds like this is probably the biggest part of the assignment.
    // It might not even be done here - maybe it's done in the Profile
    // class itself. Depends on how you want to implement it.
    profiles = loadProfiles(); 

    // Grab the first profile as a test. 
    testProfile = profiles.get(0);

    // Get whichever random profile was recommended.
    Profile recommendedProfile = testProfile.recommend();

    // Print them to the user. (You'll have to figure out how to do this best.)
    if (recommendedProfile != null)
        System.out.println("Test profile: " + testProfile.toString() +
                        " Recommended Profile: " + recommendedProfile.toString());
}
```

And a possible implementation of the `Profile` class:

```
public class Profile implements ProfileInterface
{
    // List of all friends.
    private List<Profile> friendProfiles;

    public Profile()
    {
        friendProfiles = new List<Profile>();
    }

    public Profile getRandomFriend()
    {
        if (friendProfiles.size() == 0)
            return null;
        else
            return friendProfiles.get((int)(Math.random() * friendProfiles.size())
    }

    public void addFriend(Profile friend)
    {
        friendProfiles.add(friend);
    }

    public Profile recommend()
    {
        Profile friend = this.getRandomFriend();
        return friend.getRandomFriend();
    }
}
```